# Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: cucumber/deps/com/thoughtworks/xstream/converters/ConverterRegistry

Tags: java, cucumber

I'm trying to run Cucumber Test and I'm Getting this error. I didn't found anything that helped me.
Thank you very much.

[ERROR IMAGE](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GGJy9.png)

Comment: check it out https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50932063/classnotfoundexception-during-smartsheet-login/50933357#50933357

Comment: Thanks @Sundeep, but didn't really helped

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to add the following dependency to your POM. The class is contained inside this jar.

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>io.cucumber</groupId>
    <artifactId>cucumber-jvm-deps</artifactId>
    <version>1.0.6</version>
</dependency>
```

If not using Maven download this at https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/io.cucumber/cucumber-jvm-deps/1.0.6 and add to build path.

Comment: I am using Maven. 
That case, my cucumber is 1.2.5. 
I will try. Thanks for you reply

Comment: When I run this on pom.xml with you said and 
`<dependency>
   <groupId>info.cukes</groupId>
   <artifactId>cucumber-java</artifactId>
   <version>1.2.5</version>
  </dependency>`
I get this error 

Description Resource Path Location Type
The container 'Maven Dependencies' references non existing library 'C:\Users\Diego\.m2\repository\io\cucumber\cucumber-jvm-deps\1.2.5\cucumber-jvm-deps-1.2.5.jar'

Comment: Version 1 is ancient. Latest version is 3.0.2. Atleast uograde to latest version 2 ie. 2.4.0.

Comment: Thanks for attention. I deleted everything and deleted the file ".m2" on Windows. After this, I created the project again e runned the Maven, and MVN Cucumber on pom.xml, and it worked. I did this before, but didn't worked and now, it is working.
I still hating Java. 
But, thanks a lot for support.

Comment: I am still getting this error even after adding the mentioned jar, can anyone please help

Comment: @ShilpiJoshi If u are still using info.cukes jars u should upgrade as cucumber has radically changed. If not possible, then create a new question with details. Thx

Comment: @Grasshopper No I am using io.cucumber jar